# GTA 5 Snapmatic Problem

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In Grand Theft Auto Five (GTA V/5), whenever I use the Snapmatic app on my phone while in Story or Online, I get this message when choosing the option "Upload To Gallery": Error: Snapmatic features disabled on this account due to eligibility restrictions. Other people say they have this problem as well. How is it fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are connected to the Internet had the same problem I don't know why it does it even though you are not uploading it to Facebook  or whatever press option button on ps4 pad then r1 till the gallery and they should be there